# Is there any way to create nested repeatable content in Prismic?

Tags: prismic.io

My use case is the following:

I have a page with a quiz on it, the quiz has N sections/questions and M possible answers. Both the questions and answers contain multiple fields though (e.g. an image, title and a color for each answer). I'm using a slice and putting the questions in the repeatable area, but you can't have group fields inside the repeatable area.

Any alternative ways of doing that? Wordpress Advanced Custom Fields solves this easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be no problem modelling this with slices. You would have your slice like you've described with the question and it's image etc in the non repeatable field and the answers with their images in the repeatable field.

Then in the document writing section you would call a slice for each question and select 'Add a new element to group' for each answer.

This is an example of what you json structure of your content type should look like:

```
{
  "Main" : {
    "home_title" : {
      "type" : "StructuredText",
      "config" : {
        "single" : "heading1, heading2, heading3, heading4, heading5, heading6",
        "label" : "home title",
        "placeholder" : "Home"
      }
    },
    "body" : {
      "type" : "Slices",
      "fieldset" : "Slice zone",
      "config" : {
        "labels" : {
          "mcq" : [ {
            "name" : "...",
            "display" : ""
          } ]
        },
        "choices" : {
          "Question" : {
            "type" : "Slice",
            "fieldset" : "Question",
            "description" : "Question and answers",
            "icon" : "help",
            "display" : "list",
            "non-repeat" : {
              "question" : {
                "type" : "StructuredText",
                "config" : {
                  "single" : "heading4",
                  "label" : "question"
                }
              },
              "code_snippet" : {
                "type" : "StructuredText",
                "config" : {
                  "multi" : "preformatted",
                  "label" : "code snippet"
                }
              },
              "correct_answer" : {
                "type" : "Number",
                "config" : {
                  "label" : "Correct answer"
                }
              },
              "answer_explanatrion" : {
                "type" : "StructuredText",
                "config" : {
                  "multi" : "paragraph, preformatted, heading3, heading4, heading5, heading6, strong, em, hyperlink, image, embed, list-item, o-list-item, o-list-item",
                  "label" : "Answer explanation"
                }
              }
            },
            "repeat" : {
              "answers" : {
                "type" : "StructuredText",
                "config" : {
                  "multi" : "paragraph, preformatted, strong, em, embed",
                  "label" : "Answers"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```